# add last cvs row as object in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have cvs file and i am making json out of it. like

```
date    dif   
14/12   2     1
14/12   3     1
```

like this is cvs file and result will be

```
[{x: date,y: dif ,colorType:emptyTitleRow}]
```

Code:

```
$.each(data, function(i, d) {
var x = 0;
$.each(d, function(iD, v) {
    var key = Object.keys(v);
    if (iD == 0) {
        x = v[key];
    } else if (iD <= 2) {
        if (generatedValues[key] != undefined) {
            generatedValues[key].push({
                "X": x,
                "Y": parseInt(v[key])
            });
        } else {
            generatedValues[key] = [{
                "X": x,
                "Y": parseInt(v[key])
            }];
        }
    } else {
        generatedValues[key].filter(function(i, index) {
            console.log(v[key], index);
            i['colorType'] = v[key];
        });
    }
});
});
```

**Problem:**

i am doing wrong in the last else section where **its updating one value against all records** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, d) {
var x = 0;
$.each(d, function(iD, v) {
    var key = Object.keys(v);
    if (iD == 0) {
        x = v[key];
    } else if(iD <= 2) {
        if (generatedValues[key] != undefined) {
            generatedValues[key].push({
                "X": x,
                "Y": parseInt(v[key]),
                "colorType":""
            });
        } else {
            generatedValues[key] = [{
                "X": x,
                "Y": parseInt(v[key]),
                "colorType":""
            }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
      generatedValues[key][i].colorType=v[key]
    }
});
});
```